# How to access Dictionary in for loop in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have declare a dictionary in C#. But I can't access it by foreach.

```
Dictionary<int,string>dic=new Dictionary<int,string>()
{
  {78,"A"},
  {81,"B"},
  {90, "C"}
}
```

Now I want to compare its integer value with an other variable(count). If matches then it will give corresponding string value. How can I access the dictionary by for loop??
I have tried like this.

```
foreach(int p in dic.Value)
{
   if(dic.ContainsKey(p)==count)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(dic.Values(p));
   }
}
```

It's not working. Not finding anything in any site. Help in advance.

Comment: Why would you need a for loop to do that? you can access the value of the dictionary key by just doing `dic[KEY]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate using foreach this way:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dic)
{
  if(pair.Key==count)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value); 
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this? You already know the key so you can either use `dictionaryVariableName[Key]` or `if(dictionaryVariableName.TryGetValue(Key, out stringVariableName)) { // success }` -
@NafeeurRahman fyi - This is definitely not the right answer.

Comment: @john yes we can do that also, I wasn't aware of `TryGetValue` thing

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure what you are actually trying to ask here. However, below is how to loop over the key value pairs of a dictionary using a foreach.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {78, "A"},
    {81, "B"},
    {90, "C"}
 };
//To loop over the key value pairs of a dictionary
foreach (var keyValue in dic)
{
  Console.WriteLine("This is the key: {0}",keyValue.Key);
  Console.WriteLine("This is the value: {0}", keyValue.Value);
}
```

However, i think this is what you are looking to do which requires no loop to find if the key is contained in the dictionary.

```
const int count = 78;

if (dic.ContainsKey(count))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dic[count]);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The dictionary does not contain the key: {0}", count);
}
```

As @john has mentioned in the comments, you can also use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to get the value with a specified key as well

```
string value;
var success = dic.TryGetValue(count, out value);

if (success)
    Console.WriteLine("The dictionary value is: {0}", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [example.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
      new Dictionary<string, int>();

     dictionary.Add("apple", 1);
     dictionary.Add("windows", 5);

     // See whether Dictionary contains this string.
     if (dictionary.ContainsKey("apple"))
    {
        int value = dictionary["apple"];
       Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    // See whether it contains this string.
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey("acorn"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(false);
    }
  }
```

}